# Is it possible to embed server-side vi output to a website?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, vim

I have a feeling it's a pipe-dream, but here it goes...

I'm writing a web application in django and I'd like to use vim to display contents of files on a server's NFS mounted volumes.

So, based on a visitor's information and what options she's set on the web-app, I'd like to display an embedded vim window in the browser. If possible, multiple instances of vim.

I am attached to the idea of running vim and not some of the other javascript implimentations of vim I've found because there are features in vim that I need. Such as folding, :g// and others.

Other articles I have found that don't necessarily tickle my fancy:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453051/how-to-embed-vim-editor-into-the-web-site
- http://gpl.internetconnection.net/vi/ (though this is close...)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109847/is-there-any-online-text-editor-with-vim-like-capabilities-modal-editor
- http://codemirror.net/demo/vim.html (the closest to what I'm looking for)
- http://bellard.org/jslinux/ (would be awesome, but I don't need linux, just vim. Seems excessive...)

My thinking is that the web server has access to the files, and it has vim, so why not just embed a view of vim instead of re-writing an entire text viewer/editor in python or javascript. Perhaps someone can explain why I can't embed (or create a view of) a server-side application with access to server-side files.

Thanks in advance for your replies, comments.

Comment: What kind of features do you need? Just viewing or editing? What kind of security do you need? If security is not a concern, perhaps you can use a [browser-based SSH client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH#Open_source_examples)? If you need security, you can probably look at one of those implementations for inspiration and implement your own with only interaction with vim.

Comment: It seems you can probably just modify [this](https://github.com/antonylesuisse/qweb/blob/master/ajaxterm/ajaxterm.py) to use some kind of client-server communication (e.g. [socket.io](http://socket.io/)) and you're good to go.

Comment: @univerio:  I do not see a README file on the github page you linked to.  Do we have to read over 500 lines of python to figure out what it does and how to use it?

Comment: @benjifisher If you just want to use it as a web-based SSH client out of the box, then no; you can find a README for ajaxterm [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AjaxTerm). If you want to modify it for use inside a django app using websockets, you probably need to read the code.